Can't update local files from SVN repository with git svn rebase: "needs update"
I want to update my working directory from an SVN repository. I use Git and prefer git svn to communicate with the repository. The svn-remote is set up alright, git svn fetch works as expected
I have stashed my local changes so my working directory is clean. However, when I execute git svn rebase (which is, as I understand it, akin to Git's git pull --rebase), I get a ton of messages like these
db/_UTILS/kladr_update/SOLUTION_KLADR/pkg_gar2kladr_node.pck: needs update
db/_UTILS/kladr_update/SOLUTION_KLADR/pkg_gar_dowloads.pck: needs update
db/_UTILS/kladr_update/SOLUTION_KLADR/tmp_gar_upd_info.tab: needs update

and an error code in the end
update-index --refresh: command returned error: 1

There is a db directory in the repository, but it's not present locally. I checked it out earlier but then deleted it with Windows Explorer
What should I do to update my local files successfully?

Even though you removed the folder from your disk, it's still in Git's index. Remove it from the index (-r enables recursive traversal)
git rm -r db

and then try to rebase again
git svn rebase

